# Ubuntu 20.04.2 on Virtual Box (Mac) - Flashing white screen, but no XOrg option

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, macbook-pro

I recently installed Virtual Box running Ubunto. I'm on Mac, running the latest OS.

However, once I log in, my screen flashes white, especially when I move the mouse cursor around.

From Googling, it looks like people are switching to Ubuntu XOrg (I'm new to this so I'm not sure what this means) to fix this.

However I'm not seeing an option for this when trying to login (see below image). I just see Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland. Selecting either of these before logging doesn't appear to fix the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The first entry should be the xerver. Make sure the guest additions (on your guest) have the same version number as the VB on your host

Comment: Not really sure how to do that. However I noticed if I change graphics controller to VBoxVBA or VMSVGA it works okay, but the actual ubuntu window is extremely small. It used to be large when this was set to VBoxSVGA, but it had the white flickering. For some reason, I can't get Ubuntu to open at all anymore with controller set to VBoxSVGA

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up just powering off the virtual box, then upping the video memory, before turning it on again. Seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This was a good pointer in the right direction. For me I already had video memory maxed but on the same screen checking "enable 3d acceleration" fixed my issue.